How to use a calculated variable within a PDAL pipeline
I'm using a pdal pipeline in a python project.
What I want to do is load a file (text format), calculate its resolution, then use its resolution in a filters.faceraster to create a tif. I have no trouble loading the file and can then calculate the resolution. I can even add it to the metadata and the output array. However I can't find a way to set it as the input for the "resolution" in the faceraster filter. I want to do this all in a single pipeline so that I don't load the same file twice.
I have code that works by loading the file twice, but the files can be quite large so it's a significant waste of time.
Here's the pipeline for reference ({{ instead of { are needed because it's an f string), I want to replace {resolution} with a variable calculated by myfunc (simply using a global variable doesn't seem to work, because it uses the value of the variable before myfunc is called):
    {{ 
        "type": "readers.text", 
        "filename": "{file_path}", 
        "spatialreference":"{spatial_reference}",
        "header": "X Y Z a b c"
    }},
    {{
        "type":"filters.python",
        "script":"files.py",
        "function":"myfunc",
        "module":"src.files",
        "add_dimension": "res2"
    }},
    {{
        "type":"filters.reprojection",
        "in_srs":"{spatial_reference}",
        "out_srs":"IGNF:LAMB93"
    }},
    {{
        "type": "filters.delaunay"
    }},
    {{
        "type": "filters.faceraster",
        "resolution": {resolution}
    }},
    {{
        "type": "writers.raster",
        "filename":"outputfile.tif"
    }}


Sorry, but there's no way to do this. The pipeline stages are provided arguments before any stage is run.
